# Convert string to Json Array

Tags: json, jsonserializer

I have a Dictionary like that:

```
Dictionary<string, string> // key value pair
```

and the example values are:

```
Dictionary<string, string> parameters = new Dictionary<string, string>();
parameters.Add("key1","value1");
parameters.Add("products","[{"name":"Widget A","qty":3},{"name":"Widget B","qty":1}]");
```

how Can I serialize that as :

```
vars={"key1":"value1",products":[{"name":"Widget A","qty":3},{"name":"Widget B","qty":1}]}
```

When I try to serialize :

```
vars={"key1":"value1",products":**"**[{"name":"Widget A","qty":3},{"name":"Widget B","qty":1}]**"**}
```

its append double quotes. Using JSON.Net

I'm using third party API and it accepts HashTable for parameters.

thanks

Comment: follow this link http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/272335/JSON-Serialization-and-Deserialization-in-ASP-NET

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define Dictionary object as

`Dictionary<string, object>`

instead of

`Dictionary<string, string>`.